# What are the StackOverflow UI design secrets?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-interface, javascript, design

I am sure all of you have observed the cohesive design of this site. My question is about some of the cool info-boxes that appear upon various events, such as when someone with lower reputation tries to downvote, or the long box that appears just below the browser address bar when I have a response to one of my questions.

These are basically JavaScript generated DIV elements, but do any one of you know a good library or set of controls that can be used to achieve these styling effects?

Answer (score 9):

Stackoverflow is basically the poster child for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). there are numerous plugins for popup boxes, etc. Pretty much any eye candy you'd want.

Comment: aka: Dude, you should totally drop what you're doing and use jQuery.

Comment: I see you're doing the jQuery meme wrong. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.